# SQL only join when key matches one criteria

Tags: sql

I have two tables that look like the following:

Table 1 (IDs):

```
ID    
1
2
3
4
5
```

Table 2 (Categories):

```
ID    CAT
1      A
1      B
2      A
3      A
4      B
5      A
5      B
5      C
```

What I would like to do is join table 2 to table 1 and only keep instances where there is 1) Only one match 2) That match is CAT = A

So my final table would look like:

```
ID    CAT
 2     A
 3     A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is aggregation and `having`:

```
select id, max(cat)
from t
group by id
having count(*) = 1 and
       max(cat) = 'A';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery with `not exists`:

```
select t1.id, t2.cat 
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
where t2.cat = 'A' and not exists (select 1 from table2 t3 where t3.id = t1.id and t3.cat != 'A');
```

Output:

| id | cat |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |